# Connect Python code to SQL Server database

Tags: python, sql-server

I am playing around with Python in VS Code and I can't seem to connect my code to my SQL Server database. Any suggestions? Below is the code and the error message I get when I run the code.

Code snippet:

```
from http import server
from os import name
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk
from tkinter import filedialog, Tk, Label, Button
from PIL import Image, ImageTk
import tkinter.messagebox
import pyodbc
from datetime import datetime

#Initialize the database connection
server="MAURICE-PC\\CLOCKIFY"
username="sa"
password="clockify"
database="master"
connection = pyodbc.connect("DRIVER={SQL Server};SERVER='MAURICE-PC\\CLOCKIFY';DATABASE='master';UID='sa';PWD='clockify'")
cursor = connection.cursor()
```

Error code

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "F:\Visual Studio Code Workspace\Time and Attendance\.venv\T&A.py", line 23, in <module>      
    connection = pyodbc.connect("DRIVER={SQL Server};SERVER='MAURICE-PC\\CLOCKIFY';DATABASE='master';UID='sa';PWD='clockify'")
                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
pyodbc.OperationalError: ('08001', '[08001] [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][DBNETLIB]SQL Server does not exist or access denied. (17) (SQLDriverConnect); [08001] [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][DBNETLIB]ConnectionOpen (Connect()). (123)')
```

I enabled the remote connection via SSMS, I enabled the TCP/IP protocol in SQL Server Configuration Manager and allowed the port in the firewall's incoming and outgoing connections

Comment: Is the string literal "{SQL Server}" actually the name of the driver? Or did you mean this to be a parameter with an f-string?

Comment: `SERVER='MAURICE-PC\\CLOCKIFY'` etc looks wrong, you don't use quotes, but rather: `SERVER=MAURICE-PC\\CLOCKIFY`. Have you bothered to follow some pyodbc tutorials or just wing it? One potential link: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/python/pyodbc/step-3-proof-of-concept-connecting-to-sql-using-pyodbc?view=sql-server-ver16

Comment: Did you configure the instance to listen on a fixed port? Did you enable the SQL Browser and open UDP port 1434?  Alternatively put the instance on a fixed port and use that instead of the instance name.  If you choose port 1433 you can omit the port from the connection string.

Comment: @siggemannen, thank you for your suggestion, by removing the quotes, it seemed to work perfectly. I was just winging it. Will read more tutorials etc if I get stuck again.

Answer (score 1):

Try replacing **MAURICE-PC\CLOCKIFY** with ip server address.

```
connection = pyodbc.connect("DRIVER={SQL Server};SERVER='192.168.X.X';DATABASE='master';UID='sa';PWD='clockify'")
```

Comment: "You can use the pyodbc library." this is already in the question's code. Please read the entire question and not just the title. Additionally, if you are using AI to write answers, be aware that such content is not allowed: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/421831/temporary-policy-generative-ai-e-g-chatgpt-is-banned?cb=1

Comment: @GeneralGrievance Thanks for your clarifications About AI, just i post the example iam using in project

Answer (score -1):

First, you define string variables but then you don't use them in the actual connection string. I can't test on my machine, If the SQL server set up correctly the following should work:

```
connection = pyodbc.connect(f"DRIVER={{{SQL Server}}};SERVER={server};DATABASE={database};UID={username};PWD={password};")
```

Also you might try using server ip for server address as @softghost suggested or `localhost`

Also google "python formatted strings" to gain more knowledge how to read the code in your question and in my answer